# How to pass a CTRL-D to a command line within a script?

Tags: bash, email

I am using this line

```
 ( cat bodyText.txt; uuencode backup.tar ) | mail -s "backup" myEmail@myserver.com
```

inside a bash script that will be fired by cron.

This line is almost perfect, but it hangs waiting for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to be typed, so the message and the attachement could be sent.

How do I include a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> inside a bash script to make this line work?

Comment: why you not simply use `cat bodyText.txt | uuencode backup.tar| mail -s "backup" myEmail@myserver.com`

Comment: because this will produce two emails, one containing the text and the other containing the tar.

Comment: Have you tried `( cat bodyText.txt; uuencode backup.tar ; echo -e "\n.\n" ) | mail -s "backup" myEmail@myserver.com` already?

Comment: @DigitalRobot have you tried that ? because i am receiving only one mail

Comment: this \n\n method does not works. It is expecting a Control D. Sending \n will do nothing.

Comment: You might want to try a mail client that knows how to do proper MIME attachments. perhaps [nail](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html). Or, a script in Python, using the email package, could do that.

Comment: ctrl+D means "end of file". When you do "uuencode name < file" it should act as if it did receive a ctrl+D.

Comment: I don't think the premise of the question is correct. As others have said, ctrl+D means end-of-file (more formally: causes bash to close the pipe connected to the child process's stdin). cat and uuencode shouldn't read from stdin with those arguments. mail's stdin is closed when the subshell left of the pipe ends. You say that it's hanging for ctrl-D, but I don't think that's true. What did you actually observe?

Comment: If I typed the command directly it would hang and will just execute after a control D

Comment: This works for me: echo -e "Subject: TestSubject\nFrom:from@mail.de\nTo:to@mail.de\nCONTENTOFEMAIL\n\n" | ssmtp "to@mail.de"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- the uuencode is :  uuencode  name < sourcefile
- maybe just need a final empty line : add `; echo -e "\n\n" ;` before the closing parenthesis, and try again?-

So in your case:

```
( cat bodyText.txt; uuencode backup.tar < backup.tar ; echo -e "\n\n" ; ) | mail -s "backup" myEmail@myserver.com
```

Another way is using `mutt` which handles attachments better, and knows about mime types, etc:

```
mutt -s "the subject" -a backup.tar -- myEmail@myserver.com < bodyText.txt
```

Comment: the echo is probably unneeded... I can't try it here, so try with it and try without it, and see which works ^^

Comment: not working for me. Same problem.

Comment: try :  `uuencode backup.tar backup.tar`  for the uuencode part

Comment: you may have an alias ? on your comment on @goodluck answer below, it looks as if your "uuencode something" does uuencode the file "something" ?  see `type -all uuencode` in bash and if it's an alias, try `\uuencode backup.tar backup.tar` (with "\" to bypass the alias)

Comment: I updated my answer: try the new syntax. And try the `mutt` alternative too.

Comment: `mutt` apparently behaves better when adding `--` after all the options (thus, just before the destination@host). And it always read from STDIN, so the `<bodyText.txt` is needed (or another way : `cat ... | mutt ..... -- user@host` , or `mutt .... -- user@host < /dev/null` )

Comment: your second solution works, the first don't. Thanks!!!!

Comment: you mean, without uuencode but with mutt?

Comment: no, I mean the mutt solution, the last line of code you typed. The cat line does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, Control-D is how you tell the shell to send end of file. Processes reading from streams should get end of file when the stream closes.

But it appears you're trying to implement something that already exists in more complete form. You could have reasons for that of course, but if you're interested in existing solutions, [mpack/munpack](http://ftp.andrew.cmu.edu/pub/mpack/) are command line programs that mime encode files and send via mail. You can read the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpack) to see if it does what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean:

```
uuencode backup.tar < bodyText.txt | mail -s "backup" myEmail@myserver.com
```

Comment: not working for me. The attachment arrives without the body text....

Comment: Your code to `uuencode` doesn't make any sense, and changing that part wouldn't help with the problem with `mail` in any case. You should write answers that explain the problem, not just dump a line of code: that would be more useful to readers and would help you figure out whether what you propose has a chance of solving the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use verbose mode (-v) to avoid ctrl+d

```
echo -e 'Mail body'| mail -v -s 'Mail Subject' my@email.com
```